# Calculate values returned from loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, for-loop

I created method what needs to return proper length of items:

```
@Input() items: any[];

  calculateCount(type?: string | string[]): number {
    if (typeof type === 'object') {
      for (let value of type) {
        this.items && this.items.filter((item) => item.type === value).length;
      }
      //TODO: return sum of values from loop;
    }

    if (typeof type === 'string') {
      return this.items && this.items.filter((item) => item.type === value).length;
    }
    return this.items && this.items.length;
  }
```

But I need suggestions how to return sum of values from loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the solution and found one by using `.some()` method instead of for loop calculation.
Here what I've done:

```
calculateCount(type?: string | string[]): number {

    if (Array.isArray(type)) {
        return this.items && this.items.filter((item) => type.some((someType) => someType === item.type)).length;
    }
        
    if (typeof type === 'string') {
        return this.items && this.items.filter((item) => item.type === value).length;
    }
    return this.items && this.items.length;
}
```

I hope this should be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
let total = loopitems.reduce((acc, val) => acc += val.itemToSumUp, 0);
```

loopitems being all the items needed to be counted.

itemToSumUp is the property wich you need to sum (don't use .xxx if you need the entire object.)

0 = start count from zero.